# Refreshing the map after marker change

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, gmap.net

I've added a context menu that lets you change the marker on the map. The problem is you have to close and reopen the dialog box to see the changes. What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub gmapCMS_Add()
    gmapCtrl.UpdateMarkerLocalPosition(mrk)
End Sub

Private Sub Location_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim longlat As PointLatLng = New PointLatLng(Latitude, Longitude)
            gmapCtrl.Position = longlat
            mrk = New Markers.GMarkerGoogle(longlat, Markers.GMarkerGoogleType.green)
            gmOverlay.Markers.Add(mrk)
            gmapCtrl.Overlays.Add(gmOverlay)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub gmapCMS_Add()
    gmOverlay.Markers.Remove(mrk)
    mrk = New Markers.GMarkerGoogle(gmapCtrl.Position, Markers.GMarkerGoogleType.green)
    gmOverlay.Markers.Add(mrk)
End Sub
```

Figured it out. My post on GMAP's forum is below.

https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions/655105

Comment: You can update the position of the marker and avoid creating a new marker every time.

Comment: Keep a reference to the marker and use its `SetPosition` method to update the position.